# Two way binding with angular 2

Tags: angular, model-binding

I have an input in which I am using 2-way binding syntax to populate its value like so in a separate component:

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="this.inputValue" id="itemText">
```

And in my index.html, I set the value of inputValue:

```
  onSelect: function (request, response) {
          this.inputValue = request.item;
    }
```

However, my input is updating with this new value, what am I missing?

Edit: 
The component is setup like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-leftpane-table',
  templateUrl: './leftpane-table.component.html'
})
export class LeftpaneTableComponent implements OnInit {
  inputValue:any;
  constructor(private ds: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
```

And in index.html I am setting inputValue once an item has been selected from the search results:

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8088/Badges/{query}'
    },
    onSelect: function (request, response) {
        var urlApi = 'http://localhost:8088/Badges/Details/' + request.item;
        this.inputValue = request.item;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `this` in Angular templates. Your input should look like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" id="itemText">
```

EDIT:

When you reference to `this` in `onSelect` function, you do not reference to Angular component - you reference to function. What you can do is make reference to `this` before jQuery function:

```
const componentRef = this;
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8088/Badges/{query}'
    },
    onSelect: function (request, response) {
        var urlApi = 'http://localhost:8088/Badges/Details/' + request.item;
        componentRef.inputValue = request.item;
    }
});
```

And use this reference instead `this` keyword.

Comment: The same problem persists

Comment: @TestNInja Could you provide more code? It's hard to detect an error without it.

Comment: I tried adding the reference to this before the function, however, the input field still does not display the updated value for inputValue

Comment: @TestNInja So, maybe problem is somewhere else? Try logging `componentRef.inputValue` inside `onSelect` to see if you access input model correctly. Try also logging `request` variable to see if it's correct.